# How to change default base layer in GeoNetwork 3.0?

Tags: basemap, geonetwork

GeoNetwork seems to use OpenStreetMap and MapQuest as default WMS (or WMTS), but I found nothing about that in the [documentation](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/docs.html).

Can I change it to another WMS or WMTS, if so how?

Answer (score 2):

If you enter the administration console, you will find a field where you can define the base layers (and projection and all the init configuration) of the map.

More information on the GeoNetwork documentation: http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/customizing-application/search-ui/configdefault.html